# Difference between the two sentences and their usage

Tags: grammar, syntactic-analysis

- Why don't you join a monastery?
- Why do you not join a monastery?

What's the difference between the two sentences and when do I use each of them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To my mind, the first implies that *the monastery-joiner* (let's call them) has **not considered joining a monastery before**, and the question is a suggestion to that effect. This means that it is a rhetorical question; the monastery-joiner is not expected to answer, only to consider the possibility of joining.

The second is a more direct question. It seems to imply that the monastery-joiner **has already considered joining, but has not. The question asked directly for the reason of this**.

Gramatically, they have very similar meanings, and indeed the first question could be used as a direct question as well. The contraction of 'don't' works better with the rhetorical meaning in a way that 'do you not' fails to do.

As for usage... it depends on context, but the above is a good guide.